# Removing Wine entirely

Tags: wine, software-uninstall

How can I remove Wine entirely from Ubuntu 13.10?

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get autoclean wine 
sudo apt-get remove wine 
sudo apt-get clean wine
```

but Wine has not been removed yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
dpkg -l '*wine*' | tail -n+6 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

It should list all installed `wine` packages on your system.

You can then run `apt-get remove` on them.

This command combines the above command and `apt-get remove`
(**read what packages will be removed carefully**):

```
sudo apt-get remove $(dpkg -l '*wine*' | tail -n+6 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove wine
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get autoremove wine` might help you.